# What is "The Miracle" that 10,000 fans of KimiUso voted for?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

According to the [wikia](http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Shigatsu_wa_Kimi_no_Uso), fans had a chance to vote on if they wanted a [miracle](http://www.kimiuso.jp/nodame/) to occur. This was during the run of the series. **What is this miracle?** Information in Japanese can be found on the second link but it is not easily Google Translateable.

Comment: Obviously miracle for Miyazono Kaori.

Comment: It's not quite that fans voted on whether they _wanted_ a miracle to occur. Rather, fans would tweet with the hashtag #君嘘応援 to power up Mongoose, and if Mongoose reached full power (10,000 tweets), a "miracle" might occur. My read on this is that it was a stupid marketing campaign to get people to hope that Kaori might survive and also tweet about the show a lot in the process. The show's official Twitter account does not mention this campaign even once after its conclusion (here: https://twitter.com/shigatsuhakimi/status/577277221577969664).

Comment: @AyaseEri If that had actually worked it would have been blessed af.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was confirmation for the live action or what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was the KimiUso Staff Talk Event at 2015/05/16 in Tokyo Japan.
"The Miracle” was explained by the staffs of KimiUso in this event.
http://live.nicovideo.jp/watch/lv218533566

We can not watch this live streaming already, but we can read the viewer's [blog](http://kwusbb.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/05/17/112645).
I reprint and translate the important point.

#### Japanese

> 宣伝Aさんいわく、「何も考えてなかった」と。

#### English

> PR staff A told us to "I was not thinking about anything".

As it turns out, there was no miracle.
This is the most official conclusion.

We Japanese fans are thinking that the Miracle was the staff A's Uso = Lie :p

Comment: This is a very frustrating answer but I'm glad you managed to share your research.